# How to Convert .Gif image into .Jpg in windows phone using C#

Tags: windows-phone-7

> i want to convert .gif image in .jpg using C# in windows phone
>   Application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any provision directly to use a .gif image. But one way is to get all the key images for animation and create a storyboard or you can use third party tools.

First download the image(any) using Httprequest or Webclient and then convert to jpg or png from gif(if it is gif) in the following way.

```
GifDecoder gd = new GifDecoder();
ImageTools.ExtendedImage img = new ImageTools.ExtendedImage();
gd.Decode(img, stream);              //stream means image stream
PngEncoder png = new PngEncoder();
png.Encode(img, isoFileStreamdownload);  //isoFileStreamdownload means stream, which is used to save image in image file like(image.png))
```

using ImageTools.dll, ImageTools.IO.Gif.dll,ImageTools.IO.Png.dll (Images Tools)

You can get the dll files from codeplex or just google it.